# Installing VMware Workstation issue (Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module")

Tags: vmware-workstation, debian-based

all! Just trying to install VMware Workstation 10 at Kali linux and get the following error:

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

where troubleshooting should be started?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Unable to connect to dbus - Sublime text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058926/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-unable-to-connect-to-db)

Answer (score 3):

From https://communities.vmware.com/thread/453282

> As for the GTK errors re: canberra-gtk-module, they're innocuous. You may ignore them.

I got the same Gtk-message, but the installation seems to be still proceeding.